# Unable to Interact with Floating Action Button Overlaid on WebView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

1. **Unable to Click the FloatingActionButton** : Despite being visibly present, the FloatingActionButton doesn't respond to clicks. It appears to be blocked or unresponsive.
2. **Interacting with Buttons within the WebView** : Additionally, when there's a button within the content of the WebView, positioned using a Stack, interactions (such as clicks) on the button are intercepted by the WebView itself. Clicks seem to get registered on the WebView rather than the button within it.

Here's a simplified version of my code structure:

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui_web' as ui;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Webview Example',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: WebViewWidget(),
        // Add the FloatingActionButton at a specific position
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Show a dialog box on FloatingActionButton press
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Dialog Title'),
                  content: Text('Dialog Content'),
                  actions: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: Text('Cancel'),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Perform action here
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: Text('Ok'),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WebViewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<WebViewWidget> createState() => _WebViewWidgetState();
}

class _WebViewWidgetState extends State<WebViewWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Register the WebView using platform-specific code
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'hello-world-html',
          (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
        ..width = '100%'
        ..height = '100%'
        ..src =
            'https://tv.sitedata.live/crypto-heatmap/crypto-heatmap.php?theme=light'
        ..style.border = 'none',
    );

    return const HtmlElementView(
      viewType: 'hello-world-html',
    );
  }
}```

I'm seeking advice or guidance on how to resolve these issues:

- How can I make the FloatingActionButton responsive to clicks even when overlaid on the WebView?

- Is there a way to ensure that clicks on buttons within the WebView (placed using a Stack) register on the buttons themselves rather than being intercepted by the WebView?

Any help or insights on how to manage interaction between overlaying widgets and the WebView in Flutter web would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
````